# Trying To Get a Custom Array With Looping PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Good day, i am trying to generate a csv with array below

```
array[0] => array(
  ["a"] => 1, 
  ["b"] => 1, 
  ["c"] => 1, --> the value is only 1 and 2
  ["d"] => user2, 
),
array[1] => array(
  ["a"] => 1,
  ["b"] => 1,
  ["c"] => 2,
  ["d"] => user3,
),
array[2] => array(
  ["a"] => 2,
  ["b"] => 2,
  ["c"] => 1,
  ["d"] => user4,
),
array[3] => array(
  ["a"] => 2,
  ["b"] => 2,
  ["c"] => 2,
  ["d"] => user5,
)
```

edit: i want to get the 2 array with same number on "a" and "b" value, but different in "c" value
i tried my code below

```
$results = array();

for($i = 1 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++){
    $j = $i+1;

    $response = array(
        array(
            $i, $i, 1, "user".$i
        ),
        array(
            $i, $i, 2, "user".$j
        )
    );
    array_push($results, $response);
}
```

but the array result is not as i wanted like above result. is there any solutions?, sorry for the confusion of this question, i am trying my best to ask. thank you for the help!.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You need to explain the _logic_ behind this data generation a bit better first of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to work with a for loop and a manually increments value for your `userx` value like this.

```
$results = [];
$user = 1;

for($i = 1 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++){
    $x = 1;
    $user++;
    $results[] = [$i, $i, $x, "user$user"];
    $x = 2;
    $user++;
    $results[] = [$i, $i, $x, "user$user"];
}
print_r($results);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => user2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => user3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
            [3] => user4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => user5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
            [3] => user6
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => user7
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 1
            [3] => user8
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 2
            [3] => user9
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 1
            [3] => user10
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 2
            [3] => user11
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 1
            [3] => user12
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 2
            [3] => user13
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 1
            [3] => user14
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 2
            [3] => user15
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 1
            [3] => user16
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 2
            [3] => user17
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 1
            [3] => user18
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 2
            [3] => user19
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 1
            [3] => user20
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 2
            [3] => user21
        )

)
```

I removed the `array_push()` as it is quicker (no function call) to do a simple `$arr[] = $something;`

Comment: thank you for the answer, sir. But i wanted to get 2 array with same $i, but with different $x, like the above result

Comment: Ok, second try, I understand the requirement now :)

Comment: Ok Third Attempt :) I think I finally understood the requirements this time

Answer (score 2):

1.You need to use `%` (modules operator) in your code to set `1` or `2` at third index of each of your child-array.

2.Don't create too many array/variables in your code.Do direct assignments

```
$results = array();
$j = 1;
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
    $j++;
    $results[] = array($i, $i, 1, "user".$j);
    $j++;
    $results[] = array($i, $i, 2, "user".$j);
}

print_r($results);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/GE7MD